# Trying to use easypagination.js with a variable step

Tags: jquery, global-variables, children, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm borrowing easyPaginate's code and simply trying to add on a dropdown feature to adjust the number of items displaying on each page.  My dropdown works on page 1.  The moment I click on page 2(or any other child page), the amount of items on the page increases drastically.

Would desperately love to get some help.

```
 (function($) {

$.fn.easyPaginate = function(options){

    var defaults = {
        step: 4,
        delay: 0,
        numeric: true,
        nextprev: true,
        auto:false,
        pause:0,
                    user_list:false,
        clickstop:true,
        controls: 'pagination',
        current: 'current'
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    var step = options.step;
    var lower, upper;
    var children = $(this).children();
    var count = children.length;
    var obj, next, prev;
    var page = 1;
    var timeout;
    var clicked = false;

    function show(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        lower = ((page-1) * step);
        upper = lower+step;
        $(children).each(function(i){
            var child = $(this);

            child.hide();
            if(i>=lower && i<upper){ setTimeout(function(){ child.fadeIn('fast') }, ( i-( Math.floor(i/step) * step) )*options.delay ); }
            if(options.nextprev){
                if(upper >= count) { next.fadeOut('fast'); } else { next.fadeIn('fast'); };
                if(lower >= 1) { prev.fadeIn('fast'); } else { prev.fadeOut('fast'); };
            };
        });

        $('li','#'+ options.controls).removeClass(options.current);

        $('li[data-index="'+page+'"]','#'+ options.controls).addClass(options.current);

        if(options.auto){
            if(options.clickstop && clicked){}else{ timeout = setTimeout(auto,options.pause); };
        };
    };

    function auto(){
        if(upper <= count){ page++; show(); }
    };

    this.each(function(){

        obj = this;

        if(count>step){

            var pages = Math.floor(count/step);
                            //counts the number of pages
            if((count/step) > pages) pages++;

            var ol = $('<ul id="'+ options.controls +'"></ul>');
            $('#navigate').prepend(ol);

            //Click on page numbers
                            if(options.numeric){
                for(var i=1;i<=pages;i++){
                $('<li data-index="'+ i +'">'+ i +'</li>')
                    .appendTo(ol)
                    .click(function(){

                        clicked = true;
                        page = $(this).attr('data-index');

                        show();
                    });
                };
            };

                            if(options.user_list){

                                $('<div style="float:right; margin-right:0;">Please select:  <select name="amount" id="amount"><option value="5">5</option><option selected="10">10</option></select></div>')                                   
                                .appendTo(ol)
                                .change(function(){
                                    step=($("#amount").val());

                                    show();
                                });
                            }


                            if(options.nextprev){
                prev = $('<li class="prev">Previous</li>')
                    .hide()

                    .click(function(){
                        clicked = true;
                        page--;

                        show();
                    });
            };

            if(options.nextprev){
                next = $('<li class="next">Next</li>')
                    .hide()
                    .click(function(){
                        clicked = true;
                        page++;
                        show();
                    });
            };

            show();
        };
    });

};

 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  I usually don't get too many responses...but good news is...this issue was with this line... var step = options.step;            Needed to add one little thing          var step = parseInt(options.step);       That fixed my issue.

Comment: Post answer to your solution and accept it. It will help the users with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out through hours of research and using firebug.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.easyPaginate = function(options){

var defaults = {
    step: 4,
    delay: 0,
    numeric: true,
    nextprev: true,
    auto:false,
    pause:0,
                user_list:false,
    clickstop:true,
    controls: 'pagination',
    current: 'current'
};

var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
var step = parseInt(options.step);
var lower, upper;
var children = $(this).children();
var count = children.length;
var obj, next, prev;
var page = 1;
var timeout;
var clicked = false;

function show(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    lower = ((page-1) * step);
    upper = lower+step;
    $(children).each(function(i){
        var child = $(this);

        child.hide();
        if(i>=lower && i<upper){ setTimeout(function(){ child.fadeIn('fast') }, ( i-( Math.floor(i/step) * step) )*options.delay ); }
        if(options.nextprev){
            if(upper >= count) { next.fadeOut('fast'); } else { next.fadeIn('fast'); };
            if(lower >= 1) { prev.fadeIn('fast'); } else { prev.fadeOut('fast'); };
        };
    });

    $('li','#'+ options.controls).removeClass(options.current);

    $('li[data-index="'+page+'"]','#'+ options.controls).addClass(options.current);

    if(options.auto){
        if(options.clickstop && clicked){}else{ timeout = setTimeout(auto,options.pause); };
    };
};

function auto(){
    if(upper <= count){ page++; show(); }
};

this.each(function(){

    obj = this;

    if(count>step){

        var pages = Math.floor(count/step);
                        //counts the number of pages
        if((count/step) > pages) pages++;

        var ol = $('<ul id="'+ options.controls +'"></ul>');
        $('#navigate').prepend(ol);

        //Click on page numbers
                        if(options.numeric){
            for(var i=1;i<=pages;i++){
            $('<li data-index="'+ i +'">'+ i +'</li>')
                .appendTo(ol)
                .click(function(){

                    clicked = true;
                    page = $(this).attr('data-index');

                    show();
                });
            };
        };

                         if(options.nextprev){
            prev = $('<li class="prev">Previous</li>')
                .hide()

                .click(function(){
                    clicked = true;
                    page--;

                    show();
                });
        };

        if(options.nextprev){
            next = $('<li class="next">Next</li>')
                .hide()
                .click(function(){
                    clicked = true;
                    page++;
                    show();
                });
        };

        show();
    };
});

};

})(jQuery);
```